# Why is my product details page showing an error when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

My product details page renders okay when I first access the page. But shows this error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.products')` when I refresh it.

Details.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import { loadProduct } from '../../data/api/api'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Detail({images=[] }) {

  const { id } = useParams();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const data = queryClient.getQueryData("products");
  const partialProduct = data.products.find((p) => String(p.id) === id);
  const placeholderData = {
    ...partialProduct,
    overview: "...",
    images: "...",
  };

  const { data: product } = useQuery(
    ["currentProduct", { id }],
    () => loadProduct(id),
    { placeholderData }
  );

  if (!product) {
    return null;
  }
  console.log(id)
  console.log(partialProduct)
  return (
    <Main>
      <Header>
        <Title>{product.title}</Title>
        
        <Description>{product.overview} 

        {partialProduct.images.length} image

        {partialProduct.images?.map(({image}) => (
        <li key={image}>
        <img
        src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products${image}`}
        className='card-img-top'
        />

        
        </li>
        ))}
        </Description>
        
    
      </Header>

    </Main>
  )
}
export default Detail;
```

Both `console.log(id)` and `console.log(partialProduct)` show a successful product response.

I have tried a few restructuring but I can't get this right.

I'd appreciate it if anyone would help me.

Comment: What value does `queryClient.getQueryData("products");` return when the component/app initially mounts? This doesn't seem much different than your previous post. Maybe you just need to again account for potentially undefined references, e.g. `data?.products.find(....`.

Comment: `queryClient.getQueryData("products");` returns an object which includes an array of products. Your suggestion to rewrite the function to `data?.products.find` corrects the error. Unfortunately, images appear on the first render but disappear on refresh. From the Javascript web console, I can tell it's a similar issue to what you had earlier enlightened `On the initial render when data has yet to be fetched (and cached) data.products is undefined.` I have shared an image of the console to use for reference. I honestly value your assistance @DrewReese

Comment: The error shown is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'partialProduct.images')`. When I delete the  `{partialProduct.images?.map(({image}) => (<li key={image}> <img ...className='card-img-top'/> </li>`, the application works flawlessly. Rewriting `{partialProduct.images.map(({image}) => (...` to `{partialProduct?.images.map(({image}) => (..` doesn't correct the error.

Comment: `partialProduct` ***depends*** on the result of `data?.products`, which is potentially undefined, so yes, you may need to continue the chain of protecting against accidental null/undefined accesses. Or provide a fallback, e.g. `const partialProduct = data?.products.find( .... ) ?? {}`. OFC if `partialProduct` is `{}` then `partialProduct.images` is obviously still undefined and will need the null-check/guard.

Comment: `partialProduct?.images` likely doesn't fix the issue because `images` is the property that is undefined when trying to do `partialProduct.images.map`.

Comment: @DrewReese.  Providing the fallback as you instructed clears the error but images disappear when I refresh the page.

Comment: Sounds sort of like a data synchronization issue. What exactly is `queryClient.getQueryData("products");`, what does it do? I suspect it functions as a "one and done" sort of thing and that the data is sometimes available, and sometimes not available, when the function is called, and the component isn't triggered to rerender when it *becomes* available to call it again and get the current data value.